# When initiating an object non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance, static-variables

I am new to java kindly help me why I am getting this error.
I already have searched against this but found no help.
It will be really appreciated!
Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

 

 public class Main{
     
     private class AdjMatrix{
        public AdjMatrix(){
        System.out.println("No parameters were given to class AdjMatrix");
        }
        void printAdjMatrix(int[][] arr){
        System.out.println("Elements are :");
 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("|" + arr[i][j] + "|" + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("_______________");
        }
    }
    
}
         
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter the vertices of graphs: ");
      int ver = sc.nextInt();
      int [][] arr = new int[ver][ver];
      AdjMatrix objMatrix = new AdjMatrix();
      objMatrix.printAdjMatrix(arr);
    }   
}

I'm getting error on this line: AdjMatrix objMatrix = new AdjMatrix();
```

Comment: `private static class AdjMatrix {`

Comment: AdjMatrix class has to be static

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps think in terms of memory management. non-static methods refer to an instance of the object i.e memory has been allocated and will be managed some place like a stack. static methods are not bound to any specific instance - memory for them is allocated just one - some place like a heap.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the class `AdjMatrix` out of the `Main` class. And remove the `private` keyword:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the vertices of graphs: ");
        int ver = sc.nextInt();
        int [][] arr = new int[ver][ver];
        AdjMatrix objMatrix = new AdjMatrix();
        objMatrix.printAdjMatrix(arr);
    }
}

class AdjMatrix{
    
    public AdjMatrix() {
        System.out.println("No parameters were given to class AdjMatrix");
    }
    
    void printAdjMatrix(int[][] arr){
        System.out.println("Elements are :");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("|" + arr[i][j] + "|" + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("_______________");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the preferred way. Another way to avoid the error is to add the class to the main method. This is technically correct, while not as useful because you can't use the `AdjMatrix` class anywhere outside the method.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the vertices of graphs: ");
        int ver = sc.nextInt();
        int [][] arr = new int[ver][ver];
        
        class AdjMatrix{

            public AdjMatrix() {
                System.out.println("No parameters were given to class AdjMatrix");
            }

            void printAdjMatrix(int[][] arr){
                System.out.println("Elements are :");

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                        System.out.print("|" + arr[i][j] + "|" + "\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println("_______________");
                }
            }
        }
        
        AdjMatrix objMatrix = new AdjMatrix();
        objMatrix.printAdjMatrix(arr);
    }
}
```